# Why doesn't CMAKE find these variables?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, googletest

I am currently trying to set up Google Test in QT Creator in windows, however CMAKE seems to have some trouble with the CMakeLists.txt given from Google.

The first error I get, is:

```
:-1: error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
```

I can seemingly fix this by adding `set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM C:/Ninja/ninja.exe)` to the .txt file.

However then I get the error: `:-1: error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed`

I also get a rather extensive "General Message" in QT - attached at the end of this post.

I also tried setting:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER C:/Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/gcc.exe)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER C:/Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/g++.exe)
```

I spent the past two days searching for people with the same/similar problem, here on SO and on various forums found. However this was also not helpful. Does someone have an idea how to correctly set up google test?

The General Message from QT can be found here: [Erorr Message by QT Creator](https://pastebin.com/KVFqx6qp)

Comment: `The CMAKE_C_COMPILER: C:/cygwin64/bin/gcc.exe is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.` - As you can see, at the time a compiler is checking, it uses previous value. Check is perfoming at `project()` time (this is noted in the build log too), so you need to set compiler before that call.

Comment: Ninja isn't a compiler, it's a generator.  First delete your CMake cache, then run your cmake command using `cmake .. -GNinja` to select the ninja generator.  It'll search for Ninja and also your compiler automatically so as long as you have them installed, you should be good to go.  If cmake is failing to find ninja, then pehaps add C:\Ninja to the %PATH% environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

The C and C++ compiler that CMake finds is differs from the one that you intend to use (Cygwin instead of MinGW).

What goes wrong in your attempt is that the cache already has a C and C++ compiler and you try to change it. Completely removing your build folder and following the proposition of the error message:

```
CC=C:/Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/gcc.exe CXX=C:/Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/g++.exe cmake.exe -GNinja C:/Users/Username/Desktop/SomeFolder/C++/gtest
```

should fix it. (Your way of doing it with passing `-D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=...` should also work).